# I have a huge crush on this guy, its actually more of a Erotomania, cause he is a famous person

Tags: sex

I tend to create scenarios with him, imagine myself in a relationship with him. My imaginations DO turn sexual at times. Like me and him in the same bed, is that pornography? Is that halal? Is that fine to do during Ramadan? I do have full control over it and I don't let it get to me. So yeah.Is it fine? Also I accidentally watched a short video about a woman seducing a man, here wasn't anything sexual in it, neither were they naked, I asked Allah for forgiveness. Is that also considered Pornography.

Comment: No thinking isn’t haram

Comment: Don’t do too much though live your life and do salah